# Resolve CLASSPATH with two JARs

Tags: java

I have a java app that needs two jar files to run.  `craftbukkit.jar` is the one that holds the main function, and `commons-dbcp-1.4.jar` is what I need to allow mysql pooling.  I am having issues getting the `CLASSPATH` to behave properly.

Can someone help point out what I am doing wrong here?

`java -Xincgc -Xmx1G -cp "craftbukkit.jar;commons-dbcp-1.4.jar" org.bukkit.craftbukkit.Main nogui`

Can't seem to find the `Main` when i do this, and without the `commonds-dbcp-1.4.jar` it fails to load properly.

Comment: Get rid of double quotes.

Comment: Fails to load properly how?  And where are these JARs located, relative to your current directory?

Comment: @RohitJain without the double quotes it starts spitting out improper usage java stuff. EDIT: `./run.sh: line 5: commons-dbcp-1.4.jar: command not found`

Comment: @HotLicks yes they are in the relative directory.

Comment: @MasterGberry, Shouldn't you add relative path to that directory to your `-cp` declaration then?

Comment: @svz they are in the same directory, my bad.

Comment: They are in which directory.  If you do DIR/ls from the command prompt, do you see them?  (And what OS are you running on?)

Comment: (Specifically, what is the Java path separator for your OS?)

Comment: (*nix uses using ":", and Windows uses ";")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `java -Xincgc -Xmx1G -cp craftbukkit.jar:commons-dbcp-1.4.jar org.bukkit.craftbukkit.Main nogui`

No quotes, and use `:`, not `;`.

Answer (score 1):

Add the line

```
Class-Path: commons-dbcp-1.4.jar
```

to Manifest.mf and make sure you leave an empty line at the end of the file assuming that `commons-dbcp-1.4.jar` is in the same directory.

Comment: Where do I put the MANIFEST.mf file?

Comment: in the META-INF folder in the jar

Answer (score 0):

Check your "path separator". Wich OS you are running on?

For Windows, path separator is ";". On Linux you should use ":"

Windows:

```
java -Xincgc -Xmx1G -cp "craftbukkit.jar;commons-dbcp-1.4.jar" org.bukkit.craftbukkit.Main nogui
```

Linux:

```
java -Xincgc -Xmx1G -cp "craftbukkit.jar:commons-dbcp-1.4.jar" org.bukkit.craftbukkit.Main nogui
```